# Possessive form for multiple owners

Tags: possessives

Suppose I want to assert that the car owned by Tom is blue. That's pretty simple; I could say:

> Tom's car is blue.

OK, but that is for a single owner. But suppose the car were owned by more than one person; by Tom, Dick, and Harry, say.

**How would I use that same general form for multiple owners?**

Would it be:

> Tom's, Dick's and Harry's car is blue.

or:

> Tom, Dick, and Harry's car is blue.

or what?

And then suppose I, not Harry, were the third owner.

**What would then be the correct form for multiple owners, where one of them is the person making the statement?**

Would it be:

> Tom's, Dick's, and my car is blue.

or:

> Tom, Dick, and my car is blue.

or perhaps even:

> Tom's, Dick, and my car is blue.

or what?

Also: what rule(s) of grammar govern this kind of thing?

thanks.

Comment: Your "pretty simple" answer at the top is wrong. best to start off correctly. "Tom's car needs repairing" or "Tom's car needs to be repaired"

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that is a wee bit of distraction! ;-) I've modified my question to focus people on the intended point of my question.

Comment: It does not help to say that an answer does not do what you asked for when in fact it does do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

**One car, two owners:**

- Tom and Harry's car needs repairing.

**Two cars, two owners:**

- Tom's car and Harry's car need repairing.

Some like: Tom's and Harry's

**One car, three owners:**

Tom, Dick and Harry's car needs repairing.

**Three cars, three owners:**

- Tom's car, Harry's car and Dick's car need repairing.

In speech, *we often do this*: Tom's car, Harry's and Dick's need repairing.

**As for two people and a pronoun, we would generally use a different form:**

**- Tom and Harry's car is blue, so is mine.

- Tom's car, Harry's car and my car are blue.**

Did I cover all the cases? :)

"Multiple owners": The limit one would use generally is three. **three** is multiple in that sense.

Comment: Well you *re-stated* one of the cases I’d mentioned, omitted the rest, and then threw in some of your own. I’m not sure how I could make this question any clearer: it is about multiple owners of a single owned object — in this case a car. It is NOT about multiple owned objects, yet so far that’s what most folk appear to be focusing on.

Comment: @tkp "it is about multiple owners of a single owned object"= **See one car, three owners** in my answer. One car= a single object owned by three people are the most one would use. You call that "multiple" owners. And I also gave you the color thing with pronoun **my and two other people**. I really did not omit anything and consider that I have answered your question to a T and only added anything as contrast i.e. the two owners and two objects.